# Why am I getting two ellipses when using the dataEllipse function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a principle coordinates plot from DAPC data using the `adegenet` package in R. The data used for the plot are:

```
> dapc_MG$ind.coord
              LD1          LD2
MGUD1   -9.405524 -0.092446808
MGUD2  -10.178221 -0.077018828
MGUD3   -8.004493 -0.223172024
MGUD4   -8.740758 -0.091989157
MGUD5   -8.891316 -0.136248422
MGUD6   -8.105366  0.957238296
MGUD7   -8.832198 -0.345634729
MGUD8   -8.484260  0.924628880
MGUD9   -8.978832 -0.126596011
MGUD10  -8.729387 -0.069143482
MGUD11  -7.211637 -0.104404732
MGUD12  -6.345985 -0.057321959
MGUD13  -8.660017 -0.113205115
MGUD14  -7.892150 -0.017548789
MGUD15  -8.813235 -0.073362348
MGUD16 -10.137858 -0.034488530
MGUD17  -8.462890 -0.069646135
MGUD18  -7.414354 -0.435114178
MGUD19 -10.067263 -0.109486111
MGUD20  -4.815789 -0.069918242
MGMD1    4.649435  0.149936267
MGMD2    4.074587 -1.355723783
MGMD3    3.862391 -1.150245800
MGMD4    5.095276 -0.243453670
MGMD5    3.388603  1.279395536
MGMD6    4.587423  0.110122511
MGMD7    5.805981 -1.688136390
MGMD8    5.992032 -1.625957602
MGMD9    3.836499 -0.429911284
MGMD10   3.632776 -0.663692457
MGMD11   4.846231 -0.620827242
MGMD12   4.648728  0.380656735
MGMD13   4.675340  0.096098822
MGMD14   4.109009  2.054348252
MGMD15   5.423083  1.925953017
MGMD16   5.661753 -1.321634663
MGMD17   4.473997  0.227259783
MGMD18   5.234144  2.154111222
MGMD19   5.347463 -1.500364562
MGMD20   4.844948 -2.150318949
MGLD1    3.750089  0.136716341
MGLD2    2.314980 -0.002332376
MGLD3    2.404047  0.001578862
MGLD4    2.878247 -0.574501378
MGLD5    4.289025  0.221731980
MGLD6    4.072082 -1.314282541
MGLD7    4.448515 -1.535511761
MGLD8    4.770242  1.864984067
MGLD9    4.727431  0.199772954
MGLD10   3.665372 -0.514571290
MGLD11   3.761236  0.118478439
MGLD12   2.740715 -0.779793448
MGLD13   4.993115  1.815394978
MGLD14   3.418433 -0.065471486
MGLD15   4.092151  1.864439810
MGLD16   4.390683 -0.201531790
MGLD17   3.004646 -0.807754677
MGLD18   3.453202  0.438770000
MGLD19   2.001394  1.956932251
MGLD20   4.806231  1.914213749
```

Using R's base `plot` package, I have generated the basic plot I want: [Plot_no_ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pW0G.png)

```
plot(dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD1"], dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD2"],
     col=cols_MG[grpMG$grp], pch=c(0:2)[pop(di_MG)],
     lwd = 2, xlab="axis1", ylab="axis2")

# Change xlim and ylim to fit
plot(dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD1"], dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD2"],
     col=cols_MG[grpMG$grp], pch=c(0:2)[pop(di_MG)],
     lwd = 2, xlab="axis1", ylab="axis2", xlim=c(-11,10), ylim=c(-5, 5))
#Add background to plot
rect(par("usr")[1],par("usr")[3],par("usr")[2],par("usr")[4],col = "lightgray")

points(dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD1"], dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD2"],
       col=cols_MG[grpMG$grp], pch=c(0:2)[pop(di_MG)],
       lwd = 2, xlab="axis1", ylab="axis2", xlim=c(-11,10), ylim=c(-5, 5))

legend("topright", c(popsMG, clustersMG),
       col = c(rep('black', 3), cols_MG), pch = c(0:2, rep(15, 5)),
       lty = FALSE, lwd = 2, cex=0.764, pt.cex = 1.5, y.intersp=1.5, bg = "lightgray")
```

Using `dataEllipse` from the `car` package, I'm trying to add group ellipses similar to [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/JwMvnovduBD86wEd_IP3MVcjIKugHIyUeFwba7ROVXFY7UgWeHO9yKxY6p8CtkhdYKw4vB4fCeR1xsgi46LKMdidV1RpCm9k6egYdA2sxa6tbus-ZBjhT9fG2yCC8KfgPQ3ZQOndysLxjzntKw56Hv6HXHGImXEd0K3qNRX5MPRjhOvfz-57jHlPJa8urrjfsFl7xEr1FPGbXC6u9oYkhSTEnqloW9pTGZ_gKkpA2OiKq5ko):

The function works as desired, but the output from the command I'm running produces a smaller ellipse inside the larger ones I am trying to draw: [Plot_with_ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTmEd.png)

```
dataEllipse(x = dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD1"], y = dapc_MG$ind.coord[,"LD2"], groups = grpMG$grp,
            center.pch = FALSE, grid = FALSE, plot.points = FALSE, add = TRUE,
            col = cols_MG, lwd = 1)
```

I've thoroughly checked the documentation for `dataEllipse` and I can't seem to identify why this duplication is occurring. I'm sure its not the default, as it doesn't happen with the example data they use. I assume that it must be something to do with how my data are structured, but I'm a but green when it comes to data wrangling. Could anyone help me identify the source of my issue?

Comment: From the help "dataEllipse superimposes the normal-probability contours over a scatterplot of the data."  The contours are plotted as defined by the levels option with a default at 0.5 and 0.95.  Also several of the variables are not defined in the above question making it difficult for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: My mistake, sorry I had a lot of variables criss crossing for group leveling and stuff.
You've pointed out the source of the problem as well, thanks very much! I overlooked that the default provides both